# Why Does My Localhost webpage take forever to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, windows-10, cpu

I wait 5-15 minutes everytime I refresh my localhost for the page to load. Could something be running in the background I don't know of or is there something wrong with my version of rails, ruby, windows, etc? My CPU jumps all over the place and I don't have anything running other than some tabs in Chrome. One second my CPU will be 8% and the next it will be 99%. I have already ended tasks that consume a lot of CPU in Windows 10.
Sorry if this is simple, I'm a newbie.

[image: Command Prompt when starting rails server and then running localhost: 3000. .]

[image: CPU jumping between 6% and 27%]

[image: CPU rose from 8% to 99% just from taking a screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You first image says it all. You have a routing error. javascript/defaults.js doesn't exist and that should be holding down your app as far as the code goes.

My second guess would be that your computer has a virus or something is wrong with it because if it goes up and down like you say in terms of performance, something must be going on.